# Duplicating path to file in command line of VIM

Tags: vim

I'm using **VIM** with **NerdTREE** and sometimes I get 2x,3x same paths in command line:

```
/vagrant/pr/app/Config/feeds-import.yaml/vagrant/pr/app/Config/feeds-import.yaml
```

sometimes:

```
/vagrant/pr/app/somefile.php/vagrant/pr/app/somefile.php/vagrant/pr/app/somefile.php
```

I have this lines in my **.vimrc:**

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%F

" Auto change the directory to the current file I'm working on
autocm BufEnter * if expand('%:p') !~ '://' | cd %:p:h | endif
```

How can I fix it? or maybe there is a way to reload command line - so it shows only 1 path to a file?

Comment: It looks like you are re-sourcing your `vimrc` too often. Can we have a look at the whole file?

Comment: @romainl thank you man, I just tried it - you're right, after resourcing it I got 2 paths.

Comment: `set statusline+=%F` is the culprit.

Comment: @romaini thank you very much for your help, can you post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your `vimrc`:

```
set statusline+=%F
```

appends the file path to the current statusline.

If you keep re-sourcing your `vimrc` that line is executed again and again.

I suggest the following instead:

```
set statusline=%F
```